# Limit download and upload speed using Python 3

Tags: python

I am wondering if you know how can I limit upload and download speed using python.
(I know that it can be done via Windows settings, but I need to know how I can do it using python).

Comment: You need to give context here, what download speed? Are you running a file server and want to limit the speed users are downloading files. Or are you talking about limiting the download speed in your home network, or on your laptop/desktop? Just saying I need to limit download speed is meaningless.

Comment: he means it as he said it, global windows download speed throttling